# JavaScript url in json returns 501 but string url does not

Tags: javascript, html, http, icloud

So I have the following problem:

I try to pull data from iCloud using CloudKit (HTTP requests)
The iCloud entity contains a CKAsset and I need the download URL which a POST request to `https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/...` returns. However, if I try to download the data from this URL, it returns a 501 error but if I print the URL to the console and paste that into the browser, the browser downloads the file.

It gets even weirder because if I implement the URL I printed to the console directly into the code everything works! I am converting the URL in the JSON response to a string so IDK what's wrong.

CloudKit response:

```
{ "records" : [ { "recordName" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "recordType" : "xxxxxxx", "fields" : { "file" : { "value" : { "fileChecksum" : "AZJ1FbmpL7caqaksfwrFm3586o5+", "size" : 303, "downloadURL" : "https://cvws.icloud-content.com/B/AZJ1Fbmpxxxaxxxxxxx/${f}?xxxxxxxx..." }, "type" : "ASSETID" },},} ] }
```

I shorted the response so that it only contains the relevant stuff.

I tried to get the URL with the following code: `var url = data["records"][0]["fields"]["file"]["value"]["downloadURL"];`

Already tried with `.toString()` and `var url == "" + data["records"]....`

It works if I do `var url = "https://cvws.icloud-content.com/B/AZJ1Fbmpxxxaxxxxxxx/${f}?xxxxxxxx..."` but obviously this is no real solution.

Help is really appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the code that downloads the file from `downloadURL`. I'm using a library called zip.js because the file is a zip file (with a different file extension):

```
zip.createReader(
new zip.HttpReader(url),
function (reader) {
  reader.getEntries(async function (entries) {
    if (entries.length) {
      entries[0].getData(
        new zip.TextWriter(),
        async function (text) {

          reader.close(function () {
            // onclose callback
          });
        },
        function (current, total) {
          // onprogress callback
        }
      );
    } else {
    }
  });
},
function (error) {
  // onerror callback
}
);
```

EDIT 2:

I found out something that might be interesting: If I paste the URL directly into the code, status code 200 returns from disk cache. I tried loading the website in incognito mode and I had to reload once to get it working. Because I receive a new download ID on every refresh, it can't cache a status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution. This has nothing to do with the actual URL, it is fine, but rather the way how zip.js downloads data. It first makes a HEAD request and because the iCloud servers do not support these, it returns 501. The static domains worked because it somehow cached 200 OK, even though 501 returned.

Thank you to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1):

This works if the URL is valid

You need to look in the network tab to see what is the matter. For example the ${f} looks suspicious

```js
const data = {
  "records": [{
    "recordName": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "recordType": "xxxxxxx",
    "fields": {
      "file": {
        "value": {
          "fileChecksum": "AZJ1FbmpL7caqaksfwrFm3586o5+",
          "size": 303,
          "downloadURL": "https://cvws.icloud-content.com/B/AZJ1Fbmpxxxaxxxxxxx/${f}?xxxxxxxx..."
        },
        "type": "ASSETID"
      },
    },
  }]
}

location = data.records[0].fields.file.value.downloadURL;
```

Comment: ${f} can be replaced with any name, it is essentially just the name of the downloaded file. Already tried replacing that with something else using .replace(). The network tab only shows 501 Not Implemented. What I just figured out is that is does a HEAD request which indeed returns 501 (i use paw to test http requests) but why does the URL that I implement manually work?

Comment: Perhaps because the ${f} is replaced with escaped string when not pasting

Comment: You're right, it does get replaced when pasting but I just tried replacing ${f} with something else and adding ${f} to the pasted url

Comment: btw the code you provided in your response works if you replace the value of downloadURL with a real URL.

Comment: I assumed as much

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have above does work to pull the URL out of the object (run code below). Are you sure that `data` holds the information in the format you're expecting and that the URL is correct?

```js
var data = { "records" : [ { "recordName" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "recordType" : "xxxxxxx", "fields" : { "file" : { "value" : { "fileChecksum" : "AZJ1FbmpL7caqaksfwrFm3586o5+", "size" : 303, "downloadURL" : "https://cvws.icloud-content.com/B/AZJ1Fbmpxxxaxxxxxxx/${f}?xxxxxxxx..." }, "type" : "ASSETID" },},} ] };

// Original
var url = data["records"][0]["fields"]["file"]["value"]["downloadURL"];

// Object notation
var url2 = data.records[0].fields.file.value.downloadURL;

console.log(url);
console.log(url2);
```

Comment: i'm sure that data contains the infomation because I'm able to print downloadURL to the console. I just tried Object notation and it doesn't work either...

Comment: Can you add the code where you're parsing and then using the URL to fetch the data?

Comment: Sure, i added it to the original post